# Using JQuery to send text from input textboxes?

Tags: jquery, input, textbox, get

Can anyone tell me how to send the text inside an input textbox?
I've been using this:

```
    $.get("registernext.php", { uname: uname, pass1: pass1, pass2: pass2, email: email },
function(data){
    $("#mainNotes").html(data);
});
```

Can anyone suggest how to get this working? :)
The text boxes have the same name as the variables I want to use.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the input boxes the id's rather than just the name and set the variables as:

```
$.get("registernext.php", { "uname": $("#uname").val(), "pass1": $("#pass1").val(), "pass2": $("#pass2").val(), "email": $("#email").val() },
function(data){
    $("#mainNotes").html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**Set:**

```
$("#someInputId").val("Value you want it to have here");
```

**Get:**

```
$("#someInputId").val(); // returns value of #someInputId
```

Answer (score 2):

To put something inside of an input textbox you have set set it's value. Input textboxes do not accept HTML inside of them.

In JQuery, you can use the `val()` function to do this, or set the Javascript `value` property on a DOM node.

If I am understanding what you want to do correctly, this is the code you would need:

```
$.get("registernext.php", 
 { uname: uname, pass1: pass1, pass2: pass2, email: email },
 function(data){
   for(var i in data){
    $("#" + i.toString()).val(data[i]);
   }
 });
```